# Put a cooldown to a command after 10 uses and on a certain person

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I would like to know how to put a cooldown of 1 hour on a command after someone used it 10 times, and put the cooldown only to this person, idk if I explained it well.

Here's the coomand that I want to put a cooldown to, if the user used it 10 times in a hour, it will tell him that he has to wait.

I hope that it's possible

```
const fs = require("fs");
const db = require('quick.db');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { find } = require('image-search-engine')
const { send } = require("process")


module.exports = {
    name : 'random',
    description : "commande Random",
    async execute(message, args) {




        const rapworld = require('./rapworld.json')
        var random = rapworld[Math.floor(Math.random() * rapworld.length)];


        const lo_artist = random.fields.location_city;
        const name_artist = random.fields.name;
        const date_artist = random.fields.bio_yearsactivestart;
        const bio_url = random.fields.bio_url;
        const image_artist = await find(`${name_artist} rapper`, {size : "Large"})





        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(name_artist)
            .setDescription(`Actif depuis ${date_artist} \nIl vient de ${lo_artist}`)
            .setURL(bio_url)
            .setImage(image_artist)

        message.channel.send(embed)
        .then(async (msg) => {
            msg.react('');

            let filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '';
            let collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter);

            collector.on ('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.count == 2){
                    db.push(user.id, name_artist);
                    message.channel.send(`**${user.tag}**, **${name_artist}** a été ajouté à votre cave !`)

                }

            });

        });









}}
```

And I want to put another cooldown, of 12 hours on the claim, always specific to one person.

So this part of the code

```
            collector.on ('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.count == 2){
                    db.push(user.id, name_artist);
                    message.channel.send(`**${user.tag}**, **${name_artist}** a été ajouté à votre cave !`)

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the official discord.js commando as they have a throttling feature which can be found [here](https://discordjs.guide/commando/throttling.html). You can do something like:

```
    const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class MeowCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'meow',
            group: 'first',
            memberName: 'meow',
            description: 'Replies with a meow, kitty cat.',
            throttling: {
                usages: 2,
                duration: 10,
            },
        });
    }

    run(message) {
        return message.say('Meow!');
    }
};
```

This will make it so if a user tries to use the meow command more than two times in ten seconds, it will not allow them to use it until the ten seconds have fully passed.

Comment: And you don't know how to put another cooldown on another part of the same code ?

Comment: Sorry didn't catch that. Could you explain what you're trying to say?

Comment: In my question I said that I wanted 2 cooldown on 2 differents parts of the code. But with your method I only can put one cooldown on all the code

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about that but you could probably think of something along the lines